# Python: real order of execution for equalities/inequalities in expressions?

Tags: python, python-3.x, equality, operator-precedence, boolean-expression

Imagine this "sneaky" python code:

```py
>>> 1 == 2 < 3
False
```

According to [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) all of the operators `in, not in, is, is not, <, <=, >, >=, !=, ==` have the same priority, but what happens here seems contradictory.

I get even weirder results after experimenting:

```py
>>> (1 == 2) < 3
True
>>> 1 == (2 < 3)
True
```

What is going on?

(Note)

```py
>>> True == 1
True
>>> True == 2
False
>>> False == 0
True
>>> False == -1
False
```

Boolean type is a subclass of `int` and True represents `1` and False represents `0`.

This is likely an implementation detail and may differ from version to version, so I'm mostly interested in python 3.10.

Comment: Comparison chaining: `1 == 2 < 3` is equivalent to `1 == 2 and 2 < 3`, not either of the explicitly parenthesized versions you are trying. `2 < 3` never gets evaluated, because `1 == 2` is false.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python allows you to chain conditions, it combines them with `and`. So

```
1 == 2 < 3
```

is equivalent to

```
1 == 2 and 2 < 3
```

This is most useful for chains of inequalities, e.g. `1 < x < 10` will be true if `x` is between `1` and `10`.

WHen you add parentheses, it's not a chain any more. So

```
(1 == 2) < 3
```

is equivalent to

```
False < 3
```

`True` and `False` are equivalent to `0` and `1`, so `False < 3` is the same as `0 < 3`, which is `True`.

Similarly,

```
1 == (2 < 3)
```

is equivalent to

```
1 == True
```

which is equivalent to

```
1 == 1
```

which is obviously `True`.